# Switching date formats of yyyy-mm-dd and dd/mm/yyyy to MS Access DB format of mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I need your help.

Using javascript, how can I detect which format the date is in and convert it to something that MS Access would be able to interpret?

The function should transform the date from a format of either `yyyy-mm-dd` and `dd/mm/yyyy` into

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

How on earth does one do this? It seems impossible, because my users will enter in the date format that they grew up to, but the DB in the backend does not recognize the format as being valid, therefore I need the date into a `mm/dd/yyyy` format in order to write it back to the DB.

Comment: If you know what format you've got, it's not that hard to split it up and put it back together again, but if it could be any of the three, it's not that easy, and knowing what is month and what is day is impossible in dates like `03/03/2014` unless you know what goes where.

Comment: You should use a date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets assume the only valid inputs are `yyyy-mm-dd` or `dd/mm/yyyy`, and you want `mm/dd/yyyy` back

```
function parseDate(date) {
    if ( date.indexOf('-') != -1) {
        var arr = date.split('-');
        return arr[1] + '/' + arr[2] + '/' + arr[0]
    }else{
        var arr = date.split('/');
        return arr[1] + '/' + arr[0] + '/' + arr[2]        
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6mYw7/2/)

Comment: Wow! this is certainly handy and a creative way of thinking. Thanks so much for this. This btw is beyond my level of programming but it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can build up a vba function in access, using format(str,"mm/dd/yyyy").

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great js plugin you can use to do anything with dates. http://momentjs.com/docs/